# Facebook page embedding not working for iFrames in any browser

Tags: html, facebook, iframe, facebook-iframe

I am getting error when i try to embed Facebook page using `Facebook Page Plugin`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/

[image]

Code
[image]

DO i need to select App ID or its optional, as it doesnt work for me i have created different App ID but it doesnt work with one or the other page which i try to embeb. I have tried same on different browser but Embed code doesnt show on page on FF browser i get following error

**Firefox Can’t Open This Page
To protect your security, [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com) will not allow Firefox to display the page if another site has embedded it. To see this page, you need to open it in a new window.**

and on Chrome page show as below

This is how it looks on web page
[image]

Comment: Works fine for me. First of all, make sure the requirements listed under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins are fulfilled in your test. Second, have you tried a different browser? Firefox keeps introducing new privacy features lately, and if you have it set to block trackers, or 3rd-party cookies in general, that can also influence the functioning of these plugins.

Comment: Yes, i have cross checked on FF and Chrome also. I have updated my question with screenshot to show how it looks in Chrome